# Regex multiple groups, first group not include last group

Tags: regex

I need to match any word after the LAST `_` within a string, then match everything before that minus the `_`.

So `test_test_DAY` would return: `[ 'test_test', 'DAY' ]`.

This is what I have at the moment, which works spot on for the `DAY` section.

```
([^\_]+$)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `([^\_]+$)` captures in a single group matching 1+ times not an underscore.

You might use 2 capturing groups:

```
^(.*)_(.*)$
```

If there must be at least 1 char before and after the `_` you could change the quantifier to `+` instead of `*`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pExpBP/1)

If the pattern should take matching the underscores into account where there can not be 2 consecutive underscores, you might use 2 capturing groups with a repeating group:

```
^([^_]+(?:_[^_]+)*)_([^_]+)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^_]+` [Negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated), match 1+ times any char except _
  - `(?:_[^_]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching _ followed by any char except _
- `)`  Close group 1
- `_` Match literally
- `(` Capture group 2

  - `[^_]+` Match 1+ times any char except `_`
- `)` Close group 2
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pExpBP/2)